# How to omit `undefined` column in javascript or typescript when serialization object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, undefined

I have object like:

```
Person {
  id: '75c37eb9-1d88-4d0c-a927-1f9e3d909aef',
  user: undefined,
  title: 'Mr.',
  first_name: 'somebody',
  last_name: 'body',
  belong_organization: undefined,
  expertise: [],
  contact: undefined
}
```

when I do serialization I use loadsh omit function like:

```
toJSON() {
    return _.omit(this, ['contact']);
}
```

What I want to do is omit the property which is undefined, since  the error:

```
 `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON.
```

The column is dynamically, can not predict certain column like I did.

Comment: use `JSON.parse`. It does this automatically as is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of omit, `pickBy` and `omitBy` are preferable for this :

```js
var person = {
  id: '75c37eb9-1d88-4d0c-a927-1f9e3d909aef',
  user: undefined,
  title: 'Mr.',
  first_name: 'somebody',
  last_name: 'body',
  belong_organization: undefined,
  expertise: [],
  contact: undefined
};

const newPerson= _.pickBy(person, v => v !== undefined);

console.log(newPerson);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will omit undefined properties without any special logic.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  id: '75c37eb9-1d88-4d0c-a927-1f9e3d909aef',
  user: undefined,
  title: 'Mr.',
  first_name: 'somebody',
  last_name: 'body',
  belong_organization: undefined,
  expertise: [],
  contact: undefined
}, null, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem when you define the class. I reproduced and it still works. Below snippet could help you

```js
class Person {
  constructor(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }

  toJSON() {
    return _.omit(this, ["contact"])
  }
}

const person = new Person({
  id: "75c37eb9-1d88-4d0c-a927-1f9e3d909aef",
  user: undefined,
  title: "Mr.",
  first_name: "somebody",
  last_name: "body",
  belong_organization: undefined,
  expertise: [],
  contact: undefined,
})

console.log(person.toJSON())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```